# Save website data (may be in json) to mobile folder

Tags: php, mobile

I have a web application (developed using PHP) running on the server. Website is responsive means users can open it in mobile browsers.

Now I want when the user opens the website on their mobile browser then I want to save some data in JSON format (or any other format) on their mobile in some hidden folder and also want to retrieve the data later from the same folder whenever the website is loaded on the same mobile browser.

### Edit

I know I can save data to browser cookie/local-storage but I don't want to save there I need to save to mobile's directory.

Comment: You can't directly access the phone's storage via a web browser. You can use localStorage instead.

Comment: It may be worth reading up on the browser security model and the relationship between a web server and various kinds of web client. If you are a web developer, you absolutely need to know what browsers can do in relation to reading and writing arbitrary files on a client device.

Answer (score -1):

You can not do anything similar to what you have described with PHP and files. Your best bet is to use javascript and localStorage for saving data ond end user device. So if your data is accessible to php you can have a method which returns data to js. Than with js you can modify and store data to localStorage.

Although localStorage can only store string you can use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

```
var data = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'v': 3 };
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));
var storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
```

If you are not experienced with js I would recommend using jQuery to call the data from php back end by using

```
$.get( "test.php", function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```